# What is the purpose of creating this universe?

Tags: creation, universe

This universe have so many things that we can feel and can't feel.

What is the reason behind such a big creation? Allah states in His book:

> "Who remember Allah while standing or sitting or [lying] on their
>   sides and give thought to the creation of the heavens and the earth,
>   [saying], "**Our Lord, You did not create this aimlessly; exalted are
>   You [above such a thing]**; then protect us from the punishment of the
>   Fire." [3:191]

and it seems that everyone should have an understanding of the answer to this question then to be able to confess about it the way Allah expects from us, that the creation is not aimless.

What's the Allah's purpose for this creation? What does the Holy Quran says about it?

Comment: I voted for reopening as it is one of the most important question about the whole Dunya life and religion! Also it has not confined the answers to merely be from Quran, so that one can give an answer (_based on Hadith, intellect, science and etc._) and then bring witnesses for different parts of his answers from Quran! We better know why we are here not to be lost in its everyday routines of life, in my perspective at least.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why did God create us to worship him if he doesn't need our worship?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/458/why-did-god-create-us-to-worship-him-if-he-doesnt-need-our-worship)

Comment: No they are not dups. [Reason](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/458/why-did-god-create-us-to-worship-him-if-he-doesnt-need-our-worship#comment23616_458)

Comment: @Kowser Have a look at http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/886/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-universe

Answer (score 10):

As much as I have understood from the Shi'ite teachings this world, Dunya (*which means closer, or less precious*), is a projection of a more realistic world which we call Barzakh, being somewhat a surface to a deep universe, and Barzakh on its own is the projection of a more realistic world which we call Akherah, apparently again like a surface to a deeper universe. So that one can assume the real world a many (finite or infinite?) dimensional universe, Barzakh being comprised of a set of its subspaces and Dunya being comprised of a set of Barzakh's subspaces. I am even not sure if multi-dimension would mean 4, 5, 6 or more dimensional, maybe it would be even a fractal dimension or a real number dimensional (*NOTE. our sensed three dimensional space is full of holes in the microscopic scales so that one can even expect Dunya not being three dimensional*). Anyway, this is off-topic to this question. Death in Dunya is actually a travel from the upper surface of the universe toward inside of it, Barzakh, and resurrection would be a death from Barzakh to Akherah, again a travel toward deeper inside. The deeper volumes are also always called to be the reality behind the surface, the hidden truth by the surface. The uppest surface, Dunya, is pleased for the Worldly life but we are then warned not to forget the truth. A witness from Quran for that Akherah exists even now and Barzakh also exists for us even before our death in this surface world is [29:54]:

> يَسْتَعْجِلُونَكَ بِالْعَذَابِ وَإِنَّ جَهَنَّمَ لَمُحِيطَةٌ
>   بِالْكَافِرِينَ
>
> they urge you to hasten the punishment. and indeed, hell has been already
>   encompassing of the disbelievers {*this verse is most of the times translated not very precisely*}

that is, they are already in hell but they don't understand it. Since this world is created to show things almost irrespective of its truth:

> فَلَولا إِذ جاءَهُم بَأسُنا تَضَرَّعوا وَلـٰكِن قَسَت قُلوبُهُم
>   وَ**زَيَّنَ لَهُمُ الشَّيطـٰنُ ما كانوا يَعمَلونَ**
>
> Then why, when Our punishment came to them, did they not humble
>   themselves? But their hearts became hardened, and **Satan made
>   attractive to them that which they were doing** [6:43]

or

> ... فَيُحِلّوا ما حَرَّمَ اللَّـهُ ۚ **زُيِّنَ لَهُم سوءُ أَعمـٰلِهِم** ۗ
>   وَاللَّـهُ لا يَهدِى القَومَ الكـٰفِرينَ
>
> ... [they] make lawful what Allah has made unlawful. **Made pleasing to
>   them is the evil of their deeds**; and Allah does not guide the
>   disbelieving people. [9:37]

and many other verses reporting about this pleasing mechanism, a most important mechanism of Dunya acting against the Humans and Jinns. Also see this verse:

> لَقَد كُنتَ فى **غَفلَةٍ** مِن هـٰذا فَكَشَفنا عَنكَ **غِطاءَكَ** فَبَصَرُكَ
>   اليَومَ حَديدٌ
>
> [It will be said], "You were certainly in **unmindfulness** of this, and
>   We have **removed from you your cover**, so your sight, this Day, is
>   sharp." [50:22]

or that Allah says:

> ... إِنَّهُ يَعلَمُ الجَهرَ وَما يَخفىٰ
>
> ... Indeed, He knows what is Overt and what it [the overt thing]
>   hides. [87:7] {*This verse is not usually translated precisely*}

that is, what is known would cover what is not known, but Allah knows all. Or that Allah says:

> فَسُبحـٰنَ الَّذى بِيَدِهِ مَلَكوتُ كُلِّ شَىءٍ وَإِلَيهِ تُرجَعونَ
>
> So exalted is He in whose hand is the **realm of all things**, and to Him
>   you will be returned. [36:83]

Also see the following verse which report a same news about this world having a hidden truth covered by a surface which we call Dunya:

> إِنَّ الَّذينَ يَكتُمونَ ما أَنزَلَ اللَّـهُ مِنَ الكِتـٰبِ
>   وَيَشتَرونَ بِهِ ثَمَنًا قَليلًا ۙ أُولـٰئِكَ **ما يَأكُلونَ فى
>   بُطونِهِم إِلَّا النّارَ** وَلا يُكَلِّمُهُمُ اللَّـهُ يَومَ القِيـٰمَةِ
>   وَلا يُزَكّيهِم وَلَهُم عَذابٌ أَليمٌ
>
> Indeed, they who conceal what Allah has sent down of the Book and
>   exchange it for a small price - **those consume not into their bellies
>   except the Fire**. And Allah will not speak to them on the Day of
>   Resurrection, nor will He purify them. And they will have a painful
>   punishment. [2:174]

or:

> إِنَّ الَّذينَ **يَأكُلونَ** أَموٰلَ اليَتـٰمىٰ ظُلمًا **إِنَّما
>   يَأكُلونَ فى بُطونِهِم نارًا** ۖ وَسَيَصلَونَ سَعيرًا
>
> Indeed, those who devour the property of orphans unjustly **are only
>   consuming into their bellies fire**. And they will be burned in a Blaze.
>   [4:10]

We are then giving a body which we call it the material body, but we are also given a hearth (*different than the limb, though there is a relation between them, and a better relation exists between that and brain*). The hearth is a door to the deeper inside truth. So that each person is at the same time experiencing life inside an inner universe (*to some extent having intersections with other people's inner universe*) and inside the outer universe, Dunya. When we fall into asleep, our bodily eyes are closed, but we can see, we have yet a body, we can hear and etc., if the dream is among the honest ones this is a journey in the inner universe, although if we are not treated enough we may see things symbolic, that is, not very realistically. Maybe Jinn's live in some more inner layers of Dunya, maybe Tay ul-Arz and similar things all happen in those inner layers of the universe, having seemingly more spatial dimensions than Dunya.

Now we reach to the place to be able to talk about the purpose for Allah to create the universe in such a layered structure. The answer is simple, the very creation of Humans and Jinn's require such a creation as a mean for their evolution and improvement. Allah put us in a world whose *sensed reality* is different from its *real but hidden truth*, then guides us toward the real truth and warns us not to adhere to the adornments provided in this illusion which we call Dunya:

> وَما أوتيتُم مِن شَىءٍ فَمَتـٰعُ الحَيوٰةِ الدُّنيا **وَزينَتُها** ۚ وَما
>   عِندَ اللَّـهِ خَيرٌ وَأَبقىٰ ۚ أَفَلا تَعقِلونَ
>
> And whatever thing you [people] have been given - it is [only for] the
>   enjoyment of worldly life and its **adornment**. And what is with Allah is
>   better and more lasting; so will you not use reason? [28:60]

and

> وَاصبِر نَفسَكَ مَعَ الَّذينَ يَدعونَ رَبَّهُم بِالغَدوٰةِ وَالعَشِىِّ
>   يُريدونَ وَجهَهُ ۖ وَلا تَعدُ عَيناكَ عَنهُم تُريدُ زينَةَ الحَيوٰةِ
>   الدُّنيا ۖ وَلا تُطِع مَن أَغفَلنا قَلبَهُ عَن ذِكرِنا وَاتَّبَعَ
>   هَوىٰهُ وَكانَ أَمرُهُ فُرُطًا
>
> And keep yourself patient [by being] with those who call upon their
>   Lord in the morning and the evening, seeking His countenance. And let
>   not your eyes pass beyond them, **desiring adornments of the worldly
>   life**, and do not obey one whose heart We have made heedless of Our
>   remembrance and **who follows his desire** and whose affair is ever [in]
>   neglect. [18:28]

So that Dunya is a place to choose, choose between what **intellect** orders us to do (or to avoid) and what **desire** asks us to do for it to be satisfied more and more. Allah will never force anyone by uncovering the truth, as He has said in Surah Ya-Sin:

> And there came from the farthest end of the city a man, running. He
>   said, "O my people, follow the messengers. (20) Follow those who do
>   not ask of you [any] payment, and they are [rightly] guided. (21) And
>   why should I not worship He who created me and to whom you will be
>   returned? (22) Should I take other than Him [false] deities [while],
>   if the Most Merciful intends for me some adversity, their intercession
>   will not avail me at all, nor can they save me? (23) Indeed, I would
>   then be in manifest error. (24) Indeed, I have believed in your Lord,
>   so listen to me." (25) It was said, "Enter Paradise." **He said, "I
>   wish my people could know (26) Of how my Lord has forgiven me and
>   placed me among the honored.**" (27) And We did not send down upon his
>   people after him any soldiers from the heaven, **nor would We have
>   done so**. (28)

The truth will be covered from our senses until death comes or someone treats himself to become such good that the hidden universe will be shown to him:

> وَكَذٰلِكَ نُرى إِبرٰهيمَ مَلَكوتَ السَّمـٰوٰتِ وَالأَرضِ وَلِيَكونَ
>   مِنَ الموقِنينَ
>
> And thus did We show Abraham the realm of the heavens and the earth
>   that he would be among the certain [in faith] [6:75]

Actually there are many who was known to be able to see the Barzakh before they die, seeing the realm of what they are eating (if it is Halal or not), where they are praying and etc., but to this position no one reaches unless he will first be submitted to Allah, there would be no other reason then for Allah to cover things from such a man, he has already passed the "making choice exam"!

However, you see there are many other living species that live in this world while they are not going to make a choice, this is partly because they were creatable in this universe and God never choose what to create and what not to create, and partly because we are told that the whole universe is created for us to benefit, every such species have something to do for the whole thing to remain stable and the system simply works!

Least but by no means mention that Dunya is merely a **bonus level**, for us to know our weaknesses and to improve toward a complete humanity. However, there are those who try to improve and those who want only to live the easy life. For those who try to improve this world is somewhat a bonus level, in one Qadr Night one can improve like in thousands of months, and even the whole life of a human being (*all the joys and suffers during the years which we count*) is less than a real day

> ... وَإِنَّ يَومًا عِندَ رَبِّكَ كَأَلفِ سَنَةٍ مِمّا تَعُدّونَ
>
> And indeed, a day with your Lord is like a thousand years of those
>   which you count. [22:47]
>
> قـٰلَ كَم لَبِثتُم فِى الأَرضِ عَدَدَ سِنينَ / قالوا لَبِثنا يَومًا
>   أَو بَعضَ يَومٍ فَسـَٔلِ العادّينَ / قـٰلَ إِن لَبِثتُم إِلّا قَليلًا
>   ۖ لَو أَنَّكُم كُنتُم تَعلَمونَ
>
> [Allah] will say, "How long did you remain on earth in number of
>   years?" / They will say, "We remained a day or part of a day; ask
>   those who enumerate." / He will say, "You stayed not but a little - if
>   only you had known. [23:112,113,114]

But even during such a short time one can reach to the highest rank among all the creatures of Allah, like the prophets and Imams reached such a position! However, if someone lose this opportunity then he would led toward the hell therein being purified as much as possible, and ... So that even Hell is a mean for Allah to apply his mercy to the human being, although it will be very much suffering and not as easy as the life in Dunya was, actually very very hard for our minds today to understand it, the cost for getting purified of what we have acquired by ourselves.

Godspeed

Comment: Can you write those multidimensional stuffs in a non-mathematical or non-astronomical way ? ( Not to be rude, but that sounds completely ...)

Comment: @An_Elephant, sorry to be late, I wasn't around maybe for years ... that is to say, what ever Allah has created has a realm and a face, or many faces in a tree-like fashion, so that at each stage, a creation can be considered as a realm for what follows below, and at the same time as a face for what stands above ... Dunya stays almost at the end, it is a set of only "faces", like an illusion. Dunya is real for those who live in, but is like a dream for those who watch it from outside. It is like a stage that people live their pre-defined "roles", and they should live it according to the orders

Answer (score 6):

We just know that there is A purpose and it is not a play:

> وَمَا خَلَقْنَا السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالْأَرْضَ وَمَا بَيْنَهُمَا لَاعِبِينَ
> ﴿الدخان: ٣٨﴾
>
> We created not the heavens and earth, and all that
> between them is, in play;

We just can say that Allah has created jinn and mankind to worship him.

> وَمَا خَلَقْتُ الْجِنَّ وَالْإِنسَ إِلَّا لِيَعْبُدُونِ ﴿الذاريات: ٥٦﴾
>
> I have not created jinn and mankind except to worship Me.

Comment: what is that purpose?

Comment: @Kowser We can't invent any saying against Allah. As he did not mention it then we don't know the purpose but we can say Allah has create jinn and mankind to worship him.

Comment: @Bhribayli, but the whats the reason of Creation from God's perspective?

Comment: @Bhribayli the creation of this universe is to worship ALLAH as mention in above ayah. The question is to why to worship? First you have to know the power of ALLAH n know who ALLAH is then u can worship without any doubts

Comment: @ImranAli 1. Purpose of creation of jinn and mankind is to worship Allah. It is not the purpose of creation of universe. The difference is subtle. 2. OP did not ask why we must worship Allah the original questions was on purpose of creation of universe.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the purpose of creating this universe?

Quran does not clearly state the reason why human and nature was created in the first place. But, there is a reality, they are created and they are right before our eyes. Quran brings solutions to the current state of human and nature, by warning us about the wreckage of societies (sa'at). It is not a tale or science-fiction book to talk about the physics of universe in detail.

You may bring me this ayat (verses) in contrary:

> وَمَا خَلَقْتُ الْجِنَّ وَالْإِنسَ إِلَّا لِيَعْبُدُونِ
>   And I did not create the jinn and mankind except to worship Me.
>   Zariyat 56 (51/56)

The sentence in the ayat does not state the original reason. I mean, it doesn't answer the following question

> Then, why did You feel need for someone to worship you?

and some other similar question. It only states that our primary job in life must be worshiping Allah.

As my final words;
Quran's motivation is to warn people about sa'at and show them the rightful path. The entire Quran talks about the realities that we encounter in daily life, or we are likely to encounter in future. It is not about [other universe possibilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse) nor fantastic worlds.
Quran does not cover your question. I'm not saying (and I'm not allowed to say) that Quran has no information in it about this matter. But is is for sure that it doesn't have clear and direct information on it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any specific purpose for the creation of the universe that is stated in Quran. The answer to this question might be similar to the answer given in Quran about [ruh](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%AD) (which seems to be: the answer is beyond your knowledge/understanding). However there are suggested answers by Muslim philosophers and mystics (e.g. God wanted to manifest himself) but I don't know how they support these answers.

On the other hand, Quran contains clues about the purpose of creation of humans mainly in the story of creation. The question regarding humans is similar to the one asked by angles from God in verse 2:30 when they say that *"we are exalting you with praises and glorifying for you"* . God demonstrates to the angels the reason he is creating humans: humans can *know "all of the names"* while angles are incapable of knowing them and can only *be told about them*. (The Arabic words are "علم" which can be translated as "knowledge" and "نبئ" which can be translated as "giving news".) There are diffident interpretations about what "the names" mean here, the two famous interpretations are:

- the names of everything,
- the names of God.

The later is also consistent with some Sufi and mystic views which see each prophet as a manifestation of one of God's names (e.g. Jesus is the manifestation of the name "merciful").

Answer (score 2):

**What the Quran states about Purpose:**

In Quran, surah Saad, verse 27 reads:

> وَمَا خَلَقْنَا السَّمَاءَ وَالْأَرْضَ وَمَا بَيْنَهُمَا بَاطِلًا ۚ
>   ذَ‌ٰلِكَ ظَنُّ الَّذِينَ كَفَرُوا ۚ فَوَيْلٌ لِّلَّذِينَ كَفَرُوا مِنَ
>   النَّارِ
>
> [Al-Qur’an 38:27, translator: Arberry] We have not created the heavens
>   and earth, and what between them is, for vanity; such is the thought
>   of the unbelievers, wherefore woe unto the unbelievers because of the
>   Fire!
>
> [Al-Qur’an 38:27, translator: Yusuf Ali] Not without purpose did We
>   create heaven and earth and all between! that were the thought of
>   Unbelievers! but woe to the Unbelievers because of the Fire (of Hell)!

The word b-t-l has various shades of meaning, and is generally translated as falsehood. The same word in this verse [38:27:7] has been interpreted by other translators variously as in vain, aimlessly and so on

---

**Purpose of Heavens and Earth:**

The purpose of creating the Heavens and Earth has not been spelt out for us in the Quran, but it is something that we are expected to contemplate upon, as stated in this verse:

> [Al-Qur’an 3:190-191, translator: Sahih International] Indeed, in the
>   creation of the heavens and the earth and the alternation of the night
>   and the day are signs for those of understanding. Who remember Allah
>   while standing or sitting or [lying] on their sides and give thought
>   to the creation of the heavens and the earth, [saying], "Our Lord, You
>   did not create this aimlessly; exalted are You [above such a thing];
>   then protect us from the punishment of the Fire.
>
> ---

**Purpose of Humans and dJinns:**

Our purpose is to willingly believe in and submit to the worship and service of Allah:

> [Al-Qur’an 51:56, translator: Shakir] And I have not created the jinn
>   and the men except that they should serve Me.

The following verse tells us that even those who are closest to God are not too proud to serve Him:

> [Al-Qur’an 7:206, translator: Shakir] Surely those who are with your
>   Lord are not too proud to serve Him, and they declare His glory and
>   prostrate in humility before Him.

Speaking about the entire creation, the Quran states:

> [Al-Qur’an 19:93, translator: Pickthall] There is none in the heavens
>   and the earth but cometh unto the Beneficent as a slave.

---

**Purpose of Accountability:**

> [Al-Qur’an 33:72-73, translator: Pickthall] Lo! We offered the trust
>   unto the heavens and the earth and the hills, but they shrank from
>   bearing it and were afraid of it. And man assumed it. Lo! he hath
>   proved a tyrant and a fool. So Allah punisheth hypocritical men and
>   hypocritical women, and idolatrous men and idolatrous women. But Allah
>   pardoneth believing men and believing women, and Allah is ever
>   Forgiving, Merciful.

Also, consider the following verse:

> [Al-Qur’an 30:8, translator: Sahih International] Do they not
>   contemplate within themselves? Allah has not created the heavens and
>   the earth and what is between them except in truth and for a specified
>   term. And indeed, many of the people, in [the matter of] the meeting
>   with their Lord, are disbelievers.

[http://signsandscience.blogspot.ca/teleology-purpose-built-universe.html](http://signsandscience.blogspot.ca/2014/08/teleology-purpose-built-universe.html)

Answer (score 1):

According to [*reason of creation*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7pfsyCpL-4) it is said that in Quran God Almighty created the Universe so that you can know how powerful is He and also He created the creatures to be known, so that His creatures will know Him. And also He created us to worship Him. That is one of the main reasons

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to study about the 'wahdat al wujud', which means unity of existence.

It took me a long time to understand it myself but it was worth it and because of the breadth of content it can not be covered here.

In one word,
I quote from Ghasem Kakaie :

> 'Although the creatures are
>   nonexistence, the Existence (God) has disclosed itself in them' 
>   http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11245-007-9019-7

Comment: This isn't much more than a link only answer. Please consider elaborating an answer based on your own words and understanding of your reference instead of saying "read there"!

Answer (score 0):

There is a purpose of the universe, and Allah has mentioned it clear and without doubt.

The answer is the first verse in the Quran, you all know the verse.The purpose is ٱلْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ please continue reading, as this is not a superficial guess or a response without much research.

To understand how ٱلْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ is the purpose for the whole universe, we must remember some statements in the Quran.

Al-alameen is a description of the whole universe.
Shuara 16:
فَأْتِيَا فِرْعَوْنَ فَقُولَآ إِنَّا رَسُولُ رَبِّ ٱلْعَـٰلَمِينَ ١٦
Go to Pharaoh and say, ‘We are messengers from the Lord of all worlds,
Shuara 23-24:
قَالَ فِرْعَوْنُ وَمَا رَبُّ ٱلْعَـٰلَمِينَ ٢٣
Pharaoh said: "What is the Lord of the Universe?"
قَالَ رَبُّ ٱلسَّمَـٰوَٰتِ وَٱلْأَرْضِ وَمَا بَيْنَهُمَآ ۖ إِن كُنتُم مُّوقِنِينَ ٢٤
He (Moses or Harun in behalf of Moses) said: "The Lord of The Heavens and the Earth and whatever [lies] in between them, if you will be convinced."

So Al-alameen is The Heavens and the Earth and whatever [lies] in between them,
"The Heavens and the Earth and whatever is in between them" is the Universe and beyond.

The first verse in Quran stating the purpose of the universe.
Fatiha 1:
ٱلْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ ٱلْعَـٰلَمِينَ ٢
"All Gratitude/Thankfulness/Appreciation is to Allah—Lord of Al-alameen/all worlds/The Heavens and the Earth and whatever is in between them/the whole Universe and beyond."

To understand it further we must continue to understand what is in the heavens or in Al-alameen. ٱلْعَـٰلَمِينَ Al-alameen is plural for world. One عَـٰلَمِ (Alem) means a species that share knowledge with one another living in the same world or realm. The word عَـٰلَمِ is derived from علم which means to know something. The word عَـٰلَمِ is used to describe one world or one Realm that houses a living species who have intelligence. Humankind all together with all of it nations from Adam to the last humans on judgement day is only one عَـٰلَمِ Alem. Al-alameen ٱلْعَـٰلَمِينَ describes all worlds in the universe that have intelligent species.

So if we consider or assume that the universe is empty of life, then there is no significant purpose of it. But it is full of life and it is intelligence life.
Shuara 29:
وَمِنْ ءَايَـٰتِهِۦ خَلْقُ ٱلسَّمَـٰوَٰتِ وَٱلْأَرْضِ وَمَا بَثَّ فِيهِمَا مِن دَآبَّةٍۢ ۚ وَهُوَ عَلَىٰ جَمْعِهِمْ إِذَا يَشَآءُ قَدِيرٌۭ ٢٩
"And of His signs is the creation of the heavens and the earth and the filling of them with a multitude of Terrestrial beings. And He is capable of gathering them all when He wills."

Terrestrial beings is the equivalent to دَآبَّةٍۢ, which means creatures living on land rather than in water and also rather also rather than flying beings. In Arabic you don't use دَآبَّةٍۢ for birds, fish and certainly not for angels.

In the universe there is countless worlds with multitude of living beings and each world also have an intelligent species of its own, otherwise it will not meet the criteria to be called an Alem (عَـٰلَمِ). And there will continuously be even more worlds coming into existence. And there are also angels in these worlds similar to that, there is angels here on earth.

Nahl 49:
وَلِلَّهِ يَسْجُدُ مَا فِى ٱلسَّمَـٰوَٰتِ وَمَا فِى ٱلْأَرْضِ مِن دَآبَّةٍۢ وَٱلْمَلَـٰٓئِكَةُ وَهُمْ لَا يَسْتَكْبِرُونَ ٤٩
"Whatever is in Heaven and whatever is on Earth bows down before Allah (God), whether they are living walking beings or angels, and they do not act proudly."

Rahman 29:
يَسْـَٔلُهُۥ مَن فِى ٱلسَّمَـٰوَٰتِ وَٱلْأَرْضِ ۚ كُلَّ يَوْمٍ هُوَ فِى شَأْنٍۢ ٢٩
"They pray to him who is in the Heavens and the Earth asks for something from Him; all days He is active."

Who or مَن in Arabic can only be used for intelligence beings. Like there are intelligence beings in Earth us humans, there is also intelligence beings in the heavens.

There is a reason for the creation and a purpose, which is not necessaryly the same, but it is related.

The Reason
Allah has created everyone in the universe because of his unlimited Mercy (Ar-Rahman).

The purpose
Allah has created everyone in the universe with the purpose to have Gratitude, be Thankful and appreciate the life and all goods Allah have given and provided for them. Without Gratitude/Thankfulness/Appreciation it is impossible to be happy and live a life with joy and harmony. Iblis was living in paradise, he had the highest luxury in the universe, but he did not appreciate it.

Araf 12-13:
قَالَ مَا مَنَعَكَ أَلَّا تَسْجُدَ إِذْ أَمَرْتُكَ ۖ قَالَ أَنَا۠ خَيْرٌۭ مِّنْهُ خَلَقْتَنِى مِن نَّارٍۢ وَخَلَقْتَهُۥ مِن طِينٍۢ ١٢
He said: "What prevents you from bowing down when I have commanded you to [do so]?" He said: "I am better than he is; You created me from fire, while You created him from clay."
قَالَ فَٱهْبِطْ مِنْهَا فَمَا يَكُونُ لَكَ أَن تَتَكَبَّرَ فِيهَا فَٱخْرُجْ إِنَّكَ مِنَ ٱلصَّـٰغِرِينَ ١٣
"He said, 'Descend from there (paradise), therein is not the place for you to be arrogant. So get out; indeed, you are among the losers.'"

Even if you get all the worlds, if you don’t appreciate it, you will lose it while you have it, because you can’t see the goodness and beauty in it. But there is more then just to have show appreciation. For example appreciating something good from a stranger, is not the same as the same thing giving by from a once love ones. So when your little baby child gives you a smile is a lot more than a grown up stranger giving you a smile. Because it is the love for the source that makes the appreciation more precious.  One must know that whatever is worth appreciating is from Allah. So that the source is Allah makes it priceless, because we should love Allah more than anything and anyone. We must strive to increase our love for Allah. While our love grows the appreciation will grow with it, and that is the purpose for everyone in all worlds in the universe. All real meaningful appreciation by anyone in the universe is to Allah, who is the Lord of all worlds.  ٱلْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ ٱلْعَـٰلَمِينَ

Humans from the planet Earth or children of Adam has been given a very special role or opportunity in the universe and cosmos, but that is another topic for another day.

Sad 87:
it is only a Reminder to [everyone in] the Universe

Takwir 27:
It is merely a Reminder to [everyone in] the Universe.

Dikhan 32:
"And We have certainly chosen them (children of Israel) above the worlds with knowledge."

Anbiya 107:
وَمَآأَرۡسَلۡنَٰكَ إِلَّارَحۡمَةٗلِّلۡعَٰلَمِينَ
We have sent you (and chosen your ummah) as a mercy for all worlds in the Universe.

Saffat 79:
"Peace be upon Noah throughout the Universe!"

ANAM 86:
And Ishmael, Elisha, Jonah and Lot; each We preferred over all worlds in the Universe.

Ankabut 6:
Anyone who strives, strives only for his own soul's sake. Allah (God) is Transcendent, beyond [any need of] the Universe!

Yusuf 104
You need not ask them for any payment for it; it [serves] only as a Reminder to [everybody in] the Universe.
Furqan 1:
Blessed is the One Who has sent down the Standard (the Quran) to His servant so he may (together with his ummah) be a warning for all worlds in the Universe,

Imran 42:
وَإِذْ قَالَتِ ٱلْمَلَـٰٓئِكَةُ يَـٰمَرْيَمُ إِنَّ ٱللَّهَ ٱصْطَفَىٰكِ وَطَهَّرَكِ وَٱصْطَفَىٰكِ عَلَىٰ نِسَآءِ ٱلْعَـٰلَمِينَ ٤٢
So the angels said: "Mary, Allah (God) has selected you and purified you. He has selected you over [all] the women in the Universe.

Imran 33:
۞ إِنَّ ٱللَّهَ ٱصْطَفَىٰٓ ءَادَمَ وَنُوحًۭا وَءَالَ إِبْرَٰهِيمَ وَءَالَ عِمْرَٰنَ عَلَى ٱلْعَـٰلَمِينَ ٣٣
Allah (God) selected Adam, Noah, Abraham's House and Imran's House over all worlds in the Universe.

Imran 108:
تِلْكَ ءَايَـٰتُ ٱللَّهِ نَتْلُوهَا عَلَيْكَ بِٱلْحَقِّ ۗ وَمَا ٱللَّهُ يُرِيدُ ظُلْمًۭا لِّلْعَـٰلَمِينَ ١٠٨
Those are Allah (God)'s verses which We recite to you for the Truth. Allah (God) does not want any harm or injustice for the worlds in the Universe.

Imran 96:
إِنَّ أَوَّلَ بَيْتٍۢ وُضِعَ لِلنَّاسِ لَلَّذِى بِبَكَّةَ مُبَارَكًۭا وَهُدًۭى لِّلْعَـٰلَمِينَ ٩٦
The first House set up for mankind was the one at Becca (Mecca); it was blessed and a guidance for all worlds in the Universe (Because the house started the journey of mankind from planet Earth, which are chosen as a khalifah/successor to lead all worlds in the universe and that is why Iblis had big issue not to prostrate for Adam, because the prostration was the symbol for acknowledging his superiority in the universe as a leader, like the prostration to Yusuf by his brothers was a symbolic act to acknowledge Yusuf as khalifah/successor to Yaqoob to lead the children of Israel beside his position in the land of Egypt).

Answer (score -1):

studying divine attributes and actions and studying the creation of man, guiding him by sending His messages through prophets, and His generous rewards makes it very clear that everything is based on His mercy. Indeed, the entire story of creation can be summarized in a few sentences: The Most merciful God wanted to show His mercy. 
Therefore, He created this world. He gave His mercy to human beings so that they would become His vicegerents on earth and become a means of His mercy.
https://www.al-islam.org/message-thaqalayn/vol11-n4-2011/understanding-god-s-mercy-part-1-mohammad-ali-shomali
Imam Sadiq (a) was asked by Abu Basir about the meaning of the verse 11:118-119 and Imam replied: 
خلقهم ليفعلوا مايستوجبوا به رحمته فيرحمهم
God created man so that they do something to deserve His mercy and then He would give them His mercy. (Al-Tawhid by Saduq, p. 404)
Thus, God wanted to give opportunity to people to do good deeds so that they would deserve extra mercy from Him.
https://www.al-islam.org/message-thaqalayn/vol-12-no-1-spring-2010/understanding-god-s-mercy-part-2-mohammad-ali-shomali