# Why did Allah create us?

Tags: ibadah, theology

Please give reasons for why Allah created us. If it is for 'ibadah (worship), were the angels not enough? If it is for testing us, doesn't Allah know already who will be in Paradise and who will be in Hell? So why did He put us on this earth?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/458/does-god-need-our-worship-if-no-so-why-did-god-create-humans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has 3 parts

*A) Why did Allah create us...*

> And I created the jinn and mankind not except to worship Me. (Soorah
>   Az-Zaariyaat 51:56)

So our creation purpose is to worship Allah.

*B) If it is for ibadah, weren't the angels enough...*

Angels have no free will, while we do. Allah is so majestic that creatures with free will worship Him alone.

*C) If to test us, doesn't Allah know who will go to paradise and who will not..*

Let me give you an example here....

Doesn’t your teacher know who will pass & who will fail even before the exams? She knows which students pay attention in class and which don’t, does that mean she should not test you at all?
Allah knows who will pass and who will fail.... But the test is for us.

Comment: Very nice answer. Just to add one thing more in this beautiful answer which I got while thinking and discussing this question, If ALLAH on behalf of HIS knowledge put some of us in HELL and who deserves Paradise put them in Paradise, Then we will say to ALLAH you didn't even given us a chance. We didn't even make any sin so why we are suffering HELL?