# What is the benefit of worship of Allah, for Allah?

Tags: allah, creation

This question will be discussed in the *following* my [previous question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43961/where-were-we-before-birth).

What benefits does God receive from servants worshiping? (in the following  [Insight يا رب العالمين](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/16419/insight-%D9%8A%D8%A7-%D8%B1%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%8A%D9%86)'s answer, if the goal of creating us in the mind of Allah, were our worshiping)

What is Allah needs or Allah is needless?

What exactly was the purpose of Allah for creating us? (Assuming that Allah does not need anything)

Comment: Your last question has been based on a wrong premise (according to the answer you've accepted) wouldn't it be more beneficial if you thought about the impact of such a mistake on your actual and any upcoming question first? Instead of asking another question which is based on a wrong premise in logic we say: ex falso quodlibet from something wrong we may deduce anything therefore you could only have a correct basis if your assumptions have a true/correct basis, else you will deduce any thing true or false!

Comment: Here a number of possible duplicate posts: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/458/why-we-should-worship-god-when-he-doesnt-need-our-worship, https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5905/if-allah-has-no-wants-needs-why-do-anything and https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17275/worshiping-allah-the-almighty

Comment: I read the accepted answer of above question. I cant found the benefit of our worship, for Allah in above Q&A.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, Please note that the wrong hadith was not premise of my question, entirely. That question is about our creation, reason and cause. Please note the question title in previous question. Thanks.

Comment: Noted, but your question has been addressed at least 3 times before as linked!

Comment: I understood. My question is duplicated. apologize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66866/discussion-between-medi1saif-and-mgae2m).

Answer (score 2):

Well, God Almighty Said:

> ”And I did not Create the jinn and humans except they should worship Me.” **[Noble Quran 51:56]**

And He does not need anything from us 
neither our worship because God Himself Has Said:

> ”Certainly, God stands not in need of any of the worlds.”

But it is beneficial why, because it makes us getting closer to God and that is why we’re praying to Him and also God Almighty Says:

> “And I have chosen you, so listen to that which is inspired to you.  Verily, I am God! There is none worthy of worship but I, so worship Me and offer prayer perfectly for My remembrance.” **(Quran 20:13-14)**

Also prophet Muhammad said:

> “The first matter that the slave will be brought to account for on the Day of Judgment is the prayer. If it is sound, then the rest of his deeds will be sound. And if it is incomplete, then the rest of his deeds will be incomplete.”

Oh, and take another look at this when prophet Muhammad said:

> “God has obligated five prayers. Whoever excellently performs their ablutions, prays them in their proper times, completes their bows, prostrations and khushu, has a promise from God that He will forgive him.  And whoever does not do that has no promise from God. He may either forgive him or punish him.”

This are only example of what are we benefit from praying, but there are many benefits of it. The thing that we pray to God is, that we remember Him and that praying will get us closer to Him on the day of judgement by doing good deeds and perform prayers. And praying also purify you from evil, it keeps you clean because God Almighty likes people who keeps themselves purified.

For more informations, check the site below

1. http://aboutislam.net/reading-islam/finding-peace/remembering-allah/allah-doesnt-need-prayer-obligation/

Answer (score 0):

Allah has created us to worship him not because it does a huge good thing to him it's not like he needs us we are the ones that need him so that's why worship to be rewarded not to help allah

Comment: One suggestion, if you refer to God, you have to put a capital in the beginning like Allah has created us to worship Him, use “Him” instead of “him”.

Comment: @Smarty, You said our needs. O.K. The question is: Who created us? Allah. Creating us is Allah's act. Why? What's He need? If Allah have no act creating us, what problem or need appears for Him?

Comment: @MGae2M This only He knows and we have no right to question this. We only have the job to fulfill the job He gave us which is to worship Him alone and do good just as He obligated us to do and this life is only a test, so it is all up to you if you want to be good, that’s good for you, if you want to be bad, it’s bad for you, so you have to chose.