# Quran Mushaf Eternal Speech of Allah

Tags: quran, revelation, mushaf

Assalamu Alaikum Brothers in Islam,

According to the Ahl Sunnah Wal Jamah

Is it a correct belief to hold if someone says the following:

" I affirm that the Quran is the Eternal Uncreated Speech of Allah that was revealed to the Prophet (saw). I also believe that what is written in the Mushaf is undoubtedly the Holy Quran. 
I clarify further that what is meant by the Quran in the Mushaf is not the ink or paper, but it is the "content" or the "Meaning" that is referred to as the Quran."

So to further clarify : " The paper and ink are not Eternal, but the content and meanings of the Mushaf is what is considered as the Qur'an, The Uncreated Word of Allah"

Is this the sound aqeedah?

Comment: This sounds like the orthodox Sunni doctrine, which became the prominent view from the rise of the Ash'arites and fall of the Mu'tazilites fell. Some links: [Quranic createdness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quranic_createdness) and [Islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/100585/ruling-on-describing-the-quran-as-the-eternal-word-of-allah), which is a Salifi view but he reports many relevant hadiths that are worth exploring that can be used to affirm this creed. Islamqa suggests that Ash'arites originally said the exact words of the Qur'an were eternal, but this was not held by e.g. Ghazali

Comment: See also [this Islam.SE question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5689/the-quran-is-commonly-said-to-be-the-uncreated-speech-of-allah-what-does-this?rq=1). I'm not sure if you are asking about if the creed is of the correct form or is the proper wording (which I have no clue about the creed you are referring to, if it is a specific one, etc.), or just asking about the belief of the Quran being the eternal word of God. Also, see [History of Islamic Philosophy](https://www.al-islam.org/history-muslim-philosophy-volume-1-book-3/chapter-11-asharism#4-problem-eternity-quran) discussion.